# Expand function of a sudoku solver in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, sudoku

I have difficulties to understand a part of [this](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~cs8/F2011/notes/11/Sudoku.lhs) part of a sudoku solver. I don't get how the expand function works.

```
expand                :: Matrix Choices -> [Matrix Choices]
expand m              =
   [rows1 ++ [row1 ++ [c] : row2] ++ rows2 | c <- cs]
   where
      (rows1,row:rows2) = break (any (not . single)) m
      (row1,cs:row2)    = break (not . single) row
```

What happens here? A brief explanation would be very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you link is nicely commented, fortunately. Quoting from above the function:

> The function expand behaves in the same way as collapse, except that
>   it only collapses the first square with more than one choice:

Intuitively, the function `expand` takes a sudoku and finds the first cell in which more than one choice are still possible. Then, it expands that choice, generating many sudokus each one having a particular choice. That is, it turns (roughly):

```
[ some data ... , [ data, ... [1,2,3] ... data ] , other data ]
```

into

```
[[ some data ... , [ data, ... [1] ... data ] , other data ]
,[ some data ... , [ data, ... [2] ... data ] , other data ]
,[ some data ... , [ data, ... [3] ... data ] , other data ]]
```

The key lines are these:

```
 (rows1,row:rows2) = break (any (not . single)) m
```

Here, `row` is the first row in which there's a cell having a non-single choice. `rows1,rows2` are the before/after rows in the sudoku.

```
 (row1,cs:row2)    = break (not . single) row
```

Here, `cs` is the first cell of `row` having a non-single choice. `row1,row2` are the left/right parts in that `row`.

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody else was wondering,

```
type Matrix a = [a]
type Choices  = [Value]
type Value    = Char
```

This is

```
expand m = [rows ++ ... ++ rows 2 | c <- cs]
```

where `...` is

```
[ row1 ++ ([c] : row2) ]
```

The various local variables are defined in the `where` block. In other words, we're searching the input matrix and breaking it into a pair of results.

If your question is "what does this all *mean*?", then frankly, I have no idea. This code isn't what I'd call "intuitive".